# Elements a1, ... , an are drawn from n distinct left cosets of a subgroup G, each from a different one. ...

Tags: group-theory

[question continued...]  Show that {${a_1^{-1},a_2^{-1},a_3^{-1} ... , a_n^{-1}}$} is a set of elements, each from a different right coset of G.

[Find the picture of the question itself here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD9Ke.jpg)

I get a) just struggling with the logistics of b).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: an element $x$ in the right coset $Ga_i^{-1}$ may be written as $x = ga_i^{-1} = (a_i g^{-1})^{-1}$, so $x^{-1}$ belongs to the left coset $a_iG$.

---

You have to show that the $Ga^{-1}_i$ partition $H$. This means that $\bigcup_i Ga^{-1}_i =H$ and that $Ga_i^{-1} \cap Ga_j^{-1} = 1$ for $i \neq j$. Use the hint above to deduce those properties from the analogous properties for the left cosets $a_iG$.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still struggling as to how to use this information to construct a logical mathematical proof.

Comment: @RCG See my edit.